# AWK - Select columns in a variable not input records

Tags: text-processing, awk

Assume that you have an AWK program file with a complex procedure: **example.awk**. You want to assign specific columns of a variable, rather than a whole line of the current record.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {...}
... {...}
...
END {
    ...
    var1 = ... # do something
    print "var1 ... " var1

    var2 = ⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛
    print "var2 ... " var2
}
```

Note that `var1` is independent from the file input. Run this program from a shell:

```
awk -f ./example.awk ./text.txt
...
var1 ... I like chocolate cake
var2 ... chocolate
```

As in this example, `var2` has the string that is the 3rd field/column. In the UNIX shell, it might be equivalent to

`var2=$(cut -d ' ' -f 3 <<< "$var1")`

How would you script `var2` in AWK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
awk -v f=3 '
  END {
    var1 = "I like chocolate cake"
    n = split(var1, a)
    var2 = a[f]
    print var1
    print var2
  }
' /dev/null
```

```
I like chocolate cake
chocolate
```